# Multiline macro in c (#if-#endif)

Tags: c, macros, multiline

my code:

```
#define DEBUG 3
#define TEST(...) 
    #if (DEBUG == 3) \
        printf("%s: %s\n", __FILE__, __VA_ARGS__); 
    #endif 

int main(void) {

    TEST("TEST")

    return 0;
}
```

Error: missing the binary operator before token 'printf'.

I don't understand what's the problem

Comment: it is not possble in C.

Comment: you dont need the \ on the #if line, you have other errors but thats the cause of this one

Comment: @P__J__ It’s definitely possible. You just have to invert the order of the `#if` and `#define` (i.e. `#define` conditionally).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to put the `#if` inside the macro, but C doesn't permit that kind of thing.  The reason it's failing is the `printf` **inside the #if** is unexpected.  This is a common request, but it's just not allowed.

However, you can accomplish the same thing by changing the way you do the test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEBUG 3

#if (DEBUG == 3)
# define TEST(...) printf("%s: %s\n", __FILE__, __VA_ARGS__);
#else
# define TEST(...)
#endif

int main(void) {

   TEST("TEST")

   return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: Though test-type macros like this are common, this is not a great way to do it because it can lead to unhappy surprises in debug/nondebug situations.

What happens in this case?

```
   if (something)
       TEST("blah")
   else
       TEST("no")
```

This works as you expect in debug mode, but won't even compile in production because it devolves to `if (something) else` - it doesn't even have a closing semicolon. It's easy to find other examples that are much more devious.

Hiding a semicolon inside a macro like this is usually asking for trouble, so the better approach is to make them function-like where you have to provide the semicolon yourself, and the most obvious way to do it is:

```
#  #define TEST(...) printf("%s: %s\n", __FILE__, __VA_ARGS__) // no semicolon

...
    if (something)
        TEST("blah");
    else
        TEST("no");
```

This is better and leads to less surprises, but it's still a little troublesome in that it can leave a dangling semicolon lying around, which some compilers object to.

A fix for this can be:

```
#if (DEBUG == 3)
# define TEST(...) printf("%s: %s\n", __FILE__, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
# define TEST(...) ((void)0)  // dummy statement
#endif
```

which at least quiets the compiler.  There are other approaches here too.

Answer (score 0):

In C `#define` cannot "contain" `#if`s